# insert xml data using dbfit

Tags: sql-server, unit-testing, testing, fitnesse, dbfit

I'd like to insert some test xml data into a table before executing a stored proc that parses the xml and populates another table.

```
Setup: Insert test data
|execute|!- 
 Insert into dbo.XML_Table
  Values
  (
  '<Document File="123" NoOfPages="1">
  <Page Number="1">
  </Page>
</Document>',
  GetDate()
  )
-!|
```

The query works fine in SQL Server management studio

```
Insert into dbo.XML_Table
      Values
      (
      '<Document File="123" NoOfPages="1">
      <Page Number="1">
      </Page>
    </Document>',
      GetDate()
      )
```

However, when I save the test in dbfit, it looks like this in the browser

```
Setup: Insert test data
execute
Insert into dbo.XML_Table Values ( 99, ' ', GetDate(), 'gilbert' )
```

When I run the test, it appears to execute ok. There are no errors. 
I ran SQL Server profiler and can't see the query there.

I have 30+ other tests in this project that run ok, all selecting data.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the XML markup is getting confused with HTML markup.  Try escaping the XML:

'&lt;Document File="123" NoOfPages="1"&gt;

etc

Comment: Can't believe i didn't think of that. Still not inserting the row into the database but that's another issue so i'll mark this as answered.